# How we can connect to oracle database through aws lambda python?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, aws-lambda

I have a requirement in which I need to connect to oracle database and get some data from db table. So as I am a beginner in aws lambda so i started with below example.

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

logger.info('begin lambda_handler')

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("hostname", "1521", "sid")
con = cx_Oracle.connect("user_id", "password", dsn)
cur = con.cursor()

#logger.info('username: ' + username)
#logger.info('host: ' + host)

sql = """SELECT COUNT(*) AS TEST_COUNT FROM DUAL"""

cur.execute(sql)
columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
rows = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cur]
logger.info(rows)

con.close()
logger.info('end lambda_handler')
return "Successfully connected to oracle."
```

I created below structure in linux for creating deployment package.

Parent_Directory

-lib(Under this library i placed all the oracle instant client files)

-cx_oracle files

lmbda_function.py

after deploying the package on aws lambda and testing it, I get below error.

[ERROR] DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/var/task/lib/libclntsh.so: file too short". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 29, in lambda_handler

Please somebody help me to achieve this, also if there is any better option to connect with oracle from aws lambda than please share.

Comment: As of 2022, use python-oracledb (the renamed, newest releasae of cx_Oracle), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72868805/aws-lambda-layer-for-connect-oracle-database/72876014#72876014 since this release doesn't need Oracle Client libraries.

Comment: Update: July 2022 - Please see the new python-oracledb library as the client libraries are no longer needed https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. After reading [this article](https://www.rehanvdm.com/serverless/an-unexpected-journey-with-lambda-oracledb/index.html) it looks like you are missing the `libaio.so.1` file. I am guessing you downloaded the instant client from a windows machine because from what I understand, the libaio file is not included when downloading onto the windows platform. I was able to download the `libaio.so.1` file from [this repo](https://github.com/rehanvdm/lambda-oracle-instant-client-blog/tree/master/src/lambda-layer/oracle-instant-client/lib). Just make sure to put it in the lib folder with the other oracle instant client files.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Remove the "Did you perhaps download instant client from a windows machine because from what I understand, the libaio file is not included when downloading onto the windows platform." part.

Comment: They probably did copy Instant Client from machine that used a different OS, so not just libaio will be needed but also a complete set of Instant Client libraries matching the OS that PHP is running on on Lambda.

Comment: Yea luckily, when you download the linux version of the instant client on windows, it comes with all the libraries, libaio is the only one that it doesn't come with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Snip up an Ec2 instance
2. Download cx_Oracle-7.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl - https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files
3. Download Oracle instant client - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html           (instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-21.3.0.0.0)
4. Download lib64aio1-0.3.111-1pclos2018.x86_64.rpm
5. In Ec2 instance, please follow below steps

   1. sudo yum update
   2. Install pip ( sudo yum install python3-pip) – If pip is not installed. I think by default we will get pip in Ec2. You can check the version by running command “pip3 –version”
   3. The next step is to install Pipenv. A virtual environment is a tool to keep the dependencies required by different projects in separate places, by creating virtual Python environments for them.
   4. sudo pip3 install virtualenv
   5. Virtualenv oraclelambda(some folder name), you will see a directory with name oraclelambda
   6. source oraclelambda/bin/activate
   7. Pip install cx_Oracle-7.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl  (You will notice cx_Oracle installed in oraclelambda directory)
   8. sudo yum remove libaio-0.3.109-13.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
   9. sudo yum install lib64aio1-0.3.111-1pclos2018.x86_64.rpm
   10. Next go to usr/lib64 – you will see libaio.so.1.0.1 (copy this file)
   11. Next step extract oracle instant client
   12. Paste the libaio.so.1.0.1 file into instant client folder and rename the libaio.so.1.0.1 file to libaio.so.1
   13. Next step is grab that instant client folder for instance it would be instantclient_21_3 out from the extracted zip and zip it
   14. Create new folder with name python and create the another lib folder inside the python folder.
   15. Next step is copy the python3.7 folder from oraclelambda/lib64 and place it in phthon/lib folder. The folder structure would be python\lib\python3.7\site-packages\
   16. Now zip the python folder
6. At this point we have two zip files

   1. Instantclient
   2. Python
7. The above two zip files we are going to update them in lambda layers
8. Create the lambda, update the zip files into the layers, have proper security groups created.
9. Please add below to lambda’s environment variables so that it can locate the Oracle Instant Client library.

   ```
   Key  = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   Value = /opt/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. It was resolved after I downloaded the Oracle Client library & libaio and bundled it with cx_Oracle while creating a Lambda Layer. You may follow the below video I created for this activity. Hope it is helpful to you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYiueNog-TI&ab_channel=BorrowedCloud